# Would the caloric deficit work?

Tags: diet, body-fat

I've been wondering if someone stores fat more in his legs, and has a skinny upper body, what should he do to lose this fat? should he try a caloric deficit? but since I heard that when you lose fat you lose it from your whole body then a caloric deficit will make his skinny upper body skinnier, right?

Answer (score 3):

A calorie deficit is the only way to lose fat. You can't determine which locations the fat will come off. That is mostly determined by genetics. The fat has to come from somewhere, though. So if you are in a calorie deficit long enough, it will eventually pull fat from there legs.

Comment: Worth also noting that with sufficient protein intake and resistance training stimulus, the person will also not necessarily lose muscle from their upper body, but without it, they may.